# Security rule failing with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to add a security rule so a user can only edit their own profile:

```
  "users": {

    "$user_id": {

      ".write": "$user_id == auth.uid",
```

This rule passes in the simulator but fails in real life. I thought it could be that internally the path is being encoded i.e. simplelogin:1 is converted to simplelogin%3A1 so I tried using replace to match this case but that still doesn't work.

```
      ".write": "$user_id == auth.uid.replace(':', '%3A')",
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No need to encode the uid, I use `".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"` without problems. Your rules are also exactly in line with the documentation at https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html. What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the same symptoms and after some debugging I realized the rule was ok and the real problem was the path I was using in my client code.

So I use a rule pretty similar to the one in the documentation:

```
{
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

And, if I access to the path like this:

```
ref = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/');
.
.
.
ref.child('users/' + uid).set({...
```

works just fine.